# Android Eclipse: Bitmap like a GIF

Tags: android, eclipse, bitmap, gif, sprite

How can I make my bitmap `animates` without changing its direction? Its just as same as a **GIF** picture that moves. But many forums said that it is not good to use a GIF. So how can I make my Bitmap function like a GIF? Thanks in advance and please apologize a not so useful question like this.

This is the code that I'd used:

```
    portal = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.add_portal1);
    portal = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(portal, Bitwidth,
            Bitheight, true);
    canvas.drawBitmap(portal, (mazeFinishX1 * totalCellWidth)
            + (cellWidth / 20), (mazeFinishY1 * totalCellHeight)
            + (cellWidth / 20), ball);
```

Answer (score 0):

A `.gif` is just a series of frames playing on a timer, usually repeatedly. You will need all of your frames from your .gif as `drawable` assets, played sequentially in an order, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frame_animation"
    android:oneshot="false" >
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/frame_1"
        android:duration="200"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/frame_2"
        android:duration="200"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/frame_3"
        android:duration="200"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/frame_2"
        android:duration="200"/>
</animation-list>
```

Note that this animation has three frames and bounces back and forth. You would save this code in a `drawable` folder, in a file called `simple_bounce_frames.xml` or something. Starting the animation is like so:

```
ImageView animation = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_bouncer);
animation.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.simple_bounce_frames);
```

after inflating the layout.

Comment: thanks for the help sir. But how can I insert it on my `canvas.drawBitmap`? because I already set the size of my bitmap and its position in my game. Its just I wanted to `animate` it like a `gif`.

Comment: Canvas drawing is more difficult. You will need to update at a specific time and choose a specific drawable resource. [This page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html) talks about Canvas and how it works. A more specific answer would be difficult to type up in a StackOverflow comment.